# Pass your own function to Pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I need to pass several conditions to Pandas dataframe. I have a table with cars and the year they were manufactured. For example:

```
Opel Corsa 2007
BMW X5 2017
Ford Mondeo 2015
```

Based on the current year (2022) I need to set specific labels on every car.
For example: if a car is 0 to 5 years old it is Grade A. If it's between 5 to 8 it's Grade B. And so on.

From my perspective the easiest way is to create a function which would calculate the years and then implement it to DataFrame. But is that possible.
If I have a def called grades- can I implement it to DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import date


current_year = date.today().year

df['label'] = pd.cut(
    (current_year - df['year']),
    [0, 5, 8, np.inf],
    labels=['Grade A', 'Grade B', 'other']
)
```

```
           car  year    label
0   Opel Corsa  2007    other
1       BMW X5  2017  Grade A
2  Ford Mondeo  2015  Grade B
```